# The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null' error shown while trying to get current user info from firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

[image]

Trying to get current user info after creating a new user but getting this error " The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null' " while trying to invoke ".currentUser()" method how to fix this?

here is the code the error occurs when trying to call " final  user=await _auth.currentUser();"

```
enter code here
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
final  _auth =FirebaseAuth.instance;

late String eMail;
late String password;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 200.0,
          child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 48.0,
        ),
        TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            //Do something with the user input.
            eMail=value;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8.0,
        ),

        TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            //Do something with the user input.
            password=value;
          },

        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 24.0,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                try{
                  final _newUser= await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: eMail, password: password);
                  if(_newUser!=null)
                    {
                       final  user=await _auth.currentUser();



                    }
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                  print(e);
                }

              },
              minWidth: 200.0,
              height: 42.0,
              child: Text(
                'Register',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Please copy your code, instead of uploading its image.

Answer (score 3):

solved it the problem was i was calling "final user =_auth.currentUser()" function which had been changed to "final user =_auth.currentUser" currentUser was a getter and also no need of await keyword and to get email ,uid etc from user we should check
if user is null then acess email and uid etc.

```
enter code here
final _newUser= await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: eMail, password: password);
 if(_newUser!=null)
       {

         final  user =_auth.currentUser;

             if(user!=null)
                   {
                     final email = user.email;
                      print(email);
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you should add a null check as below:

```
filan user = await _auth!.currentUser();
```

Because `_auth` can be null. Also you can use this code:

```
filan user = await _auth?.currentUser() ?? User(); // the name of user class
```

Comment: the error  sttil shows the same message after updating the code to " final  user=await 
 _auth!.currentUser();"

Comment: Did you try this: filan user = await _auth?.currentUser() ?? User();

Comment: i didint understand   what the  "User()" class meant  in  "await _auth?.currentUser() ?? User()" should i create a new class  "User" can you explain

Comment: Did you create a model for saving  _auth.currentUser() result into it?

Comment: No i haven't im not familiar with model  the only class i have written is "RegistrationScreen()" (code above )

Comment: thank you for the reply i somehow solved it the course i was following was super outdated   we should call "_auth.currentUser()"  without the paranthesis  "_auth.currentUser"  currentUser is now  a getter and we dont need the await keyword so its  "final  user =_auth.currentUser;"